# The meaning of the entries of eigenvectors of graphs

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I would like an explanation to the meaning of the different entries of the eigenvectors of a graph.

Furthermore, I'd be happy if anyone can spare an explanation for the meaning of the entries of any arbitrary vector that would be multiplied by a graph's laplacian (Let's assume vectors of length 1).

Some points to consider:

1) One eigenvector is (1,1,..,1) - what is the meaning of the 1's?

2) All other eigenvectors are orthogonal to (1,1,..,1) and sum to 0. What is the significance of them summing to 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) The fact that this vector is an eigenvector of the Laplacian is just a consequence of the definition of the Laplacian: The Laplacian is given by the adjacency matrix minus a matrix which keeps the degree of every vertex at the corresponding entry at the diagonal. If we multiply the Laplacian with the adjacency matrix, we get a vector with the degree o every vertex, which is exactly what we get when we multiply with the second matrix as well. Hence the result of subtracting one of them from the other is zero, s.t. the all ones vector becomes an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue 0.
2) We want them to be orthogonal to the vector (1,...,1), which implies that they must sum to zero by definition.